# How do you say "good grades (or marks)" in school?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word grades (or marks) can be translated into many things. I am having trouble finding the correct way to translate it into Esperanto. I am asking specifically about the grades you receive in school after an exam. Which word should I use in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the word *noto*

*Post la sukcesa ekzameno mi ricevis bonajn notojn*

According to PIV, one of its meanings is: *Taksado de ies laboro, konduto*